# Теория игр, рекурсия, поиск нужных значений

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке запустить код возникает бесконечная рекурсия (не может найти подходящие значения под условия, да и сам код неверный из-за s==42) - что изменить в коде, чтобы он действительно работал и при других заданиях (кроме 19)?

> Два игрока, Петя и Ваня, играют в следующую игру.

> Перед игроками лежит куча камней. Игроки ходят по очереди, первый ход
> делает Петя. За один ход игрок может увеличить количество камней в
> куче на 1, 3 или 7. Игра завершается в тот момент, когда количество
> камней в куче становится ровно 42. Игрок, первым получивший кучу из 42
> камней, считается победителем. Игрок получивший после своего хода
> более 42 камней считается проигравшим и победителю засчитывается ход в
> 42. Будем говорить, что игрок имеет выигрышную стратегию, если он может выиграть при любых ходах противника.
>
> 19. Укажите такое минимальное значение s, при котором Петя не может
>     выиграть за один ход, но при любом ходе Пети Ваня может выиграть своим #Ответ: 38
>     первым ходом.
> 20. Найдите два наименьших значения s, при которых у Пети есть выигрышная
>     стратегия, причём одновременно выполняются два условия:
>
> — Петя не может выиграть за один ход;
>
> — Петя может выиграть своим вторым ходом независимо от того, как будет
> ходить Ваня. Найденные значения запишите в ответе в порядке
> возрастания. #Ответ: 31, 33
>
> 21. Найдите два наименьших значение s, при котором
>     одновременно выполняются два условия:
>
> — у Вани есть выигрышная стратегия, позволяющая ему выиграть первым
> или вторым ходом при любой игре Пети; — у Вани нет стратегии, которая
> позволит ему гарантированно выиграть первым ходом. Найденные значения
> запишите в ответе в порядке возрастания #Ответ: 30, 32

```py
def f(s,p):
    if s == 42 and p == 3: return True
    #if s > 42 and p == 3: return False
    if s == 42 and p < 3: return False
    if s == 42 and p == 3: return False
    if p%2 == 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) and f(s+3,p+1) and f(s+7,p+1)
    if p%2 != 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) or f(s+3,p+1) or f(s+7,p+1)



for s in range(1,60):
    if f(s,1):
        print(s)
```

Comment: странная формулировка условия, в нём не упоминается, что  s - это начальное количество камней в куче.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможный ответ на 19 вопрос:

```py
def f(s,p):
    if s == 42 and p == 3: return True
    if s > 42 and p < 3: return True
    if s < 42 and p > 3: return False
    if s > 49 and p > 3: return False
    if p%2 == 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) or f(s+3,p+1) or f(s+7,p+1)
    if p%2 != 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) and f(s+3,p+1) and f(s+7,p+1)



for s in range(1,41):
    if f(s,1):
        print(s) #38, 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s,p):
    if s >= 42 and p == 3: return True
    if s > 42 and p < 3: return False
    if s+1 > 42 and s+3 > 42 and s+7 > 42: return False
    if p%2 == 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) and f(s+3,p+1) and f(s+7,p+1)
    if p%2 != 0:
        return f(s+1,p+1) or f(s+3,p+1) or f(s+7,p+1)
```

Comment: условие поставлено неверно (>42 означает проигрыш для того, кто получил столько камней за ход)